# Pandas drop rows having certain values belonging to specific categorical variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
   Variable Value1 Value2 Value3
    A          1      2      3
    B          1      5      6
    C          2      4      3
    D          4      2      1
    A          0      0      0
    B          0      0      0
    C          0      0      0
```

and I want to discard rows of B and C having values 0 for the outcome to look like this

```
       Variable Value1 Value2 Value3
        A          1      2      3
        B          1      5      6
        C          2      4      3
        D          4      2      1
        A          0      0      0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the condition with `all` and `isin`

```
out = df.loc[~(df['Variable'].isin(['B','C']) & df.filter(like='Value').eq(0).all(1))]
  Variable  Value1  Value2  Value3
0        A       1       2       3
1        B       1       5       6
2        C       2       4       3
3        D       4       2       1
4        A       0       0       0
```